# PHP or die and if else conditional idiosyncrasies

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have function that performs a `mysql_query()` and then does some other stuff.
I want to be able to perform another `mysql_query()` only if the first one succeeds.

Here is the function

```
function myFunction($qtext)
{
  mysql_query($qtext) or die(mysql_error() . "\n");
  //do some more stuff
  return true;
}
```

I'm calling the function and attempting to check if it failed with an if else conditional...

```
if(!myFunction($query_text))
{
  echo "first query failed";
}
else
{
  mysql_query($query_text1) or die (mysql_error() . "\n");
}
```

This seems to work when the first query passes, but if the first query fails it goes to the `or die` and returns the `mysql_error()` text and the `echo "first query failed";` line in the conditional is never reached.

Ideally id like to be able to alert the user with the mysql_error text but without `or die`ing, so I can run more code in the conditional.

Any help with explanations of behavior is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

p.s.
I'm a beginner... I'm not sure if Im using the `return true;` properly in the function

Comment: First of all, you should use PDO, not bare mysql API.
Dieing script just because mysql_query failed is not also very good practice. Use exceptions.

Comment: your first function returns true no matter what.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Comment: Use `$success || die('FAILURE');` to die on error rather that `or`, or will always die

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're always returning `true` in the function - you need to also return `false` if you're checking it in an `if()` statement.

```
function myFunction($qtext) {

    // run the query
    $sql = mysql_query($qtext);

    // see if there was a result (or whatever you're checking)
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        // do some more stuff
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, you *really* should learn `mysqli` or `POD` instead of `mysql`, as `mysql` is depreciated. I also recommend you don't use `die()` unless you're testing. Build an error handling function instead - it's actually quite easy and will handle errors gracefully instead of abruptly killing the script and annoying your users. You also don't want to print error messages directly to your browser because it can compromise your site's security. :)

Just an FYI: I use a database class and run my queries like this. It's fast and clean.

```
if($db->get_results("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$db->escape($email)."'")) {
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent "or die" from happening, replace it with return false:

```
function myFunction($qtext)
{
    $result = mysql_query($qtext);
    if ($result === false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //do some more stuff
    return true;
}
```

that way your check later on will work and condition will fire. You don't have to use "or die", that is reserved for the cases where you want to halt all execution.

Answer (score 0):

`die()` kills the script instantly. That function will never return any value if you call `die()` inside it, you will never be able to perform other queries. Only the destructors of instanced object are still ran after a `die()` call, and with several restrictions.

If you want to be able to continue doing stuff after a query fails, you must never call `die()`. Instead, just check if `mysql_query()` returned `FALSE` as [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676141/156811) suggested. Note the `===` operator, its important to a proper error check here.

If you still want to print the error like `die()` would, use `print()`  or `echo` instead.